# RxSwift - Repeat observable until predicate

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm fairly new to RxSwift and have been banging my head against the following problem for two days now.

I wrapped a closure that reads a partial JSON formatted string from an API:

```
func readResult() -> Observable<String> {
    return Observable<String>.create { observable -> Disposable in
        API.readValue() { (result: Result<String>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let value): observable.onNext(value)
            case .failure(let error): observable.onError(error)
            }
            observable.onCompleted()
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

As the result from `readValue` only contains a chunk of the JSON formatted string, and I need to recursively call this method to get the full string. Therefore, it is important to start a new reading only when the previous one has finished.

I tried using an `Observable.timer` and `scan` to accumulate the results until I can successfully decode the json, but using a `timer` does not guarantee that the previous reading finished.

I also thought about using `concat` but as I don't know the length of the full JSON string in advance, I cannot write something like this:

```
Observable.concat(readResult(), readResult())
```

How could I ensure that the `readResult` function gets called until I can successfully decode the resulting JSON string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, *.reduce()* should be the right tool for the job.

Not sure why are you building Observable from scratch the hard way instead of using *.from()* factory method.

I would probably do it as follows (pseudocode):

```swift
let subject = PublishSubject<Observable<String>>.create()
let result = subject.switchLatest().reduce { /* update result */ }
subject.onNext(
        Observable.from( /* service call */ ).subscribeOn( /* some serial scheduler */ )
) // repeat as needed
```

**UPDATE**

See the more specific solution in comments.

Comment: I simplified the service call for the example. Using the `.from()` factory method isn't possible in my case, hence the hard way of doing things.

How can I know how often I need to repeat the `onNext` call without knowing in advance the number of chunks?

Comment: I see, you don't know the number of chunks in advance and you cannot do calls in parallel. Maybe have a look at how it is done here - https://github.com/maxvol/RxCloudKit/blob/master/RxCloudKit/RecordFetcher.swift and here https://github.com/maxvol/RxCloudKit/blob/master/RxCloudKit/CKRecord%2BRx.swift

Comment: If I understand the links correctly, the `RecordFetcher` class recursively calls the `setupAndAdd` method until the cursor has reached the end upon which the `.completed` event is send to the observer. I see how I could use this in my use case.

Comment: Indeed, and the operations ensure that calls are done sequentially once the previous one is finished.

Comment: That did the job! Great way to combine the imperative and reactive worlds. Should I create a separate answer with my code, or should I accept this answer and provide a gist to my solution (in case anyone else runs into the same kind of problem).

Comment: Better accept this one and provide gist in comment ;)